# SQL Server Trigger does not update all table records

Tags: sql-server, trigger, ms-access, update

This is my first question so please go easy on me. We are using Access 2013 as a front-end and SQL Server 2012 with MS SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60 backend with ODBC connections.

I am trying to write a series of triggers to update a couple of different tables. When I paste the data manually in Access (our front-end) the trigger only updates 71 of 80 records of the sample data. If I disable all triggers and pull out only the query portion all of the records (80) are updated. Why is my trigger not updating the entire table?

Here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_Update_Inventory_Ind_Trees_Abs_Plot_Numb]
   ON  [dbo].[Plot_Location]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
    if @@rowcount = 0
RETURN
    UPDATE Inventory_Ind_Trees
    SET Inventory_Ind_Trees.Abs_Plot_Numb = Plot_Location.Abs_Plot_Numb
    FROM Plot_Location
    WHERE Plot_Location.Invent_Plot_ID = Inventory_Ind_Trees.Invent_Plot_ID
```

The portion I run as a stand alone query that updates the entire table is here:

```
UPDATE Inventory_Ind_Trees
SET Inventory_Ind_Trees.Abs_Plot_Numb = Plot_Location.Abs_Plot_Numb
FROM Plot_Location
WHERE Plot_Location.Invent_Plot_ID = Inventory_Ind_Trees.Invent_Plot_ID
```

The records that are not updated are left as NULL. I am able to change them manually but I want this to be an automatic process.

Any suggestions where to look for the answer, or any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I only want to update the new records that have been put into the *Inventory_Ind_Trees* table with the corresponding *Abs_Plot_Numb* values from the *Plot_Location* table, but I was not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your trigger is updating all rows.  Modify it to use the `inserted` virtual table, something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_Update_Inventory_Ind_Trees_Abs_Plot_Numb]
ON [dbo].[Plot_Location]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Inventory_Ind_Trees
    SET Inventory_Ind_Trees.Abs_Plot_Numb = Plot_Location.Abs_Plot_Numb
    FROM Plot_Location
    WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM inserted i 
            WHERE i.Invent_Plot_ID = Plot_Location.Invent_Plot_ID
        )
        AND Plot_Location.Invent_Plot_ID = Inventory_Ind_Trees.Invent_Plot_ID;
END
```

This may not be *exactly* correct; it's hard to tell exactly where to join the `inserted` virtual table with your other tables.  Essentially, the idea is the `inserted` virtual table only contains rows that were either inserted or updated in the `Plot_Location` table.

You shouldn't check the `@@ROWCOUNT` system function at the start.  [It may not reflect the  rowcount you think it does](http://web.archive.org/web/20090502165051/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/steve_kass/archive/2009/04/29/It_2700_s-2008-and-rowcount-ain_2700_t-what-it-used-to-be.-Don_2700_t-use-it-in-triggers_2100_.aspx).  Instead you should select the count of rows in the `inserted` table.  Like this:

```
DECLARE @rc INT;
SELECT @rc = COUNT(1)
FROM inserted;

IF @rc > 0
BEGIN
    --body of trigger  goes here.
END
```

Comment: better to SET SET Inventory_Ind_Trees.Abs_Plot_Numb = inserted.Abs_Plot_Numb FROM Inventory_Ind_TreesJOIN direct with inserted - INNER JOIN inserted ON Inventory_Ind_Trees.Invent_Plot_ID = inserted.Invent_Plot_ID

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It makes sense to only update the inserted rows instead of the entire table. The WHERE EXISTS @MaxVernon provided seems to work well but it is only updating the number of rows in the inserted table. Is there a way to update all records in Inventory_Ind_Trees (sample data has 80 records) with the Abs_Plot_Numb values from the Plot_Location table?